# @font-face can't work on chrome of mac os

Tags: fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans CJK SC Light';
  src: url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light-Alphabetic.eot');
  src: url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light-Alphabetic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light-Alphabetic.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light-Alphabetic.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light-Alphabetic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/src/assets/font/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Light.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans CJK SC Light', Roboto, -apple-system, ..., "Microsoft YaHei", SimSun, sans-serif;
}
```

on chrome of ubuntu, the font of my web app is 'Noto Sans CJK SC Light'. But on macos, in safari and chrome, the font is 'system-ui'. How can I make the @font-face woking on chrome of mac?

Comment: From the above code I see you missing source for woff's, ttf and svg. Try adding that to your CSS. Also have you tried a full path for the font? You can using browser plugins to test which fonts are rendered.

Comment: Missing source for woff, ttf and svg? But I indicated them in src. Are there any problems?

Comment: You are missing `src:`

Comment: Can't use ',' connect url?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Sine you know what the system font is on Mac you should be able to put it in your font family to use it.

```
font-family: 'Noto Sans CJK SC Light', 'system-ui', [other fallback fonts];
```

Let me know if this works.

Cheers

Comment: ```font-family: 'Noto Sans CJK SC Light', Roboto, -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont;``` It can't work..

Comment: Which coding language are you using?

Comment: typescript. Use angular2

Comment: Then please ask the question that makes sense. I am not an angular person. Please update your question to include everything including the code to display fonts. If you are having trouble have a look at the page that tells you how to ask a "proper" question!